# Display users related to specified group

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-8

I need to display only users which is in a group.
For example, I have two fields group and assigned to.
   If i select a group, then i should get only list of that group.

Can you provide any solution for this problem please

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter function. Press "Add custom filter" and select "Groups" in the first line, "is equal to" in the second and your group name in the third.
Then press apply.

Comment: This is from user interface but i need coding. So may i get sample code for this?